# Is there any way, as of current, to check if my script is being called as a module in deno?

Tags: node.js, module, deno

As the title says. For example, I can check for the following in node:

```js
if(process.main===module) console.log('This is being called as a module');
```

Is there any way, as of current, that I can check for the same thing in deno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `import.meta.main`, which will be `false` if it is called from a module.